# How to embed google drive video only on my website

Tags: c#, asp.net, google-drive-api, embed

i want to ask about the idea of embedding google drive video to my website.

To give more details, i have videos on my google drive account, i want to share these videos to my website, so my website users can see them after login to my website.

i tried "any one with the link" but actually if anyone get the link then they can view the video which is not my goal, im also avoiding using the option of specific people as i want my website users to view it only.

is this applicable ? maybe using APIs ?

my project is asp.net

Comment: Consider that you have two services in question here.  One is your website, one is Google Drive.  They don't share any sort of authentication or really know anything about each other.  From the Google Drive perspective, you're either sharing it to anyone who has that link or you're not.  If you decide not to share to anyone with the link then your website will need a way to get the video on the back-end and send it to the user. Which means the video is going to stream through your web server, which will both download from Google and upload to the user, increasing bandwidth usage significantly.

Comment: should also mention that this is probably against Google Drive's terms and condition

Answer (score 0):

Perhaps using something such as Google Sign-In and storing the video on something such as Google Cloud Storage may work better for your needs.

https://developers.google.com/identity/sign-in/web/

https://cloud.google.com/storage/docs/?hl=en_US&_ga=2.45789092.-1485116680.1546457475

There is documentation available for .net on the google cloud.

https://cloud.google.com/dotnet/